# Select a single box and add css to it

Tags: javascript, html

I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dhavalnagar/oss3061q/5/) code which creates grid.

The relevant HTML part is:

```html
<canvas id = "grid" width = 400; height = 400; style="border:1px solid #000000;" ></canvas>
```

While the Javascript snippet:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("grid");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var i ,j;

function grid(x, y, wid, height) {
            ctx.beginPath();
                //Drawing Grid 
            for(i=0; i <= height; i+=x) {
                ctx.moveTo(0, i);
                ctx.lineTo(wid, i);
             }

            for(j=0; j <= wid; j+=y) {
                ctx.moveTo(j, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(j, height);
             }
            }

            // Function to draw grid
            //grid(x, y, width, height);
            grid(10, 10, 400, 400);

            ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
            ctx.stroke();
```

Here, I want to add some css styles to some boxes of grid. How do I do this? Any ideas? In short if I want to select any box of this grid, what should I do? I'm willing to change my whole code even if needed.

Comment: Do not introduce `css` in `canvas`. You have many(repaint) options in canas to achieve this..

Comment: actually, i not just want to paint a single box, i also want to add some behaviors to it such as when someone click on it do something. So for that i need to select a particular box (am i right?).

Comment: you are simply drawing a bitmap image when you use canvas. use svg element or d3.js library to fullfil your requirement